# Use a function as input for another function

Tags: matlab

Hi I am new to matlab so not familiar with its grammar.
I want to write a function to solve some functions using specific algo.

What I want to do is to write a function using another function which I want to slove as input.

For example, if I want to get the root of x^2 - 1 = 0 ,I need to plug in this function as in input.

my code is like

```
function [y] = brent(f, x0, x1, max_iter, tolerance)

fx0 = f(x0)
fx1 = f(x1)
......

end
```

f is the function I want to solve. My question is how should I write the code so the function 'brent' can use the function 'f' to calculate the values at specific points.

ex. In the second line, I need to get the value of f(x0) (x0 is a point).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matlab talks about function handles. Those can be input parameter as anything:

Write your main function:

```
function a = func(f,x)
   a = f(x) + 7;
```

Define your function to be input, and call 'normally'

```
>> myfun = @(x) x^2-1;
>> func(myfun,3)
ans =
        15
>> func(@sin,0)
ans =
        7
```

see:
https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/creating-a-function-handle.html

Comment: Further, functions defined in-line as in your `myfun` are called "[anonymous functions](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html)".